# Application Entrypoint

Tags: php

I'm building an application and using index.php as and entry point to different modules. I noticed SugarCRM does this and it appears like a good idea.

The URL Looks like this
http://www.mypage.com/index.php?mod=log&pag=login

Where *mod* is the module and *pag* is the page

The index.php looks line this:

```
<?PHP

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

// Class Loader
require ('app/inc/app_autoload.php');

// HTML Header with js and css links
require ('header.php');

// Content Page
$url_module = $_GET["mod"];
$url_page = $_GET["pag"];

$content = $url_module."/".$url_page.".php";
// For the above URL $content = log/login.php

if (!file_exists ($content)) {
    require ($content);
    }else{  
    // Handle Error
}

// Footer
require ('footer.php');

?>
```

Is this safe? 
If it's safe, Is it in line with practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be potentially unsafe. Depends on all the other PHP files that PHP can open. If all of them are class files that don't execute anything, then you're safe. However, if any of them execute something automatically...maybe not.

Let's say that you have PHP files inside a folder:

```
/secured/file.php
```

And let's say that the folder has an .htaccess that prohibits anyone from navigating to the page directly. Or better, let's say it's above your root directory. However, the hacker sends "../secured" as the value of `mod` and "file" as the value of page. In such a case, PHP may allow the person to include that file, and if it self-executes, it may have unintended consequences.

This is why Zend Framework requires explicit configuration of all MVC paths. Other frameworks allow for a some dynamic inclusion, but they often do something like append "Controller.php" to the end of the string, which ensures that the file included must be a Controller...and thus intended to be included in such a way.

When it comes to security, the best thing you can do is make sure that YOU...with all the knowledge of the entire server...can't open up any file that you don't want to be opened by someone else. If you can't get the code to do it, knowing what files are there, then you have implemented some decent (though likely still not flawless) security.